# PHPUnit how to write a Laravel Nova Observer test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I would like to write a test for my CommentObserver. This observer is only registered in the NovaServiceProvider but not the AppServiceProvider. This means I cannot test my observer by using my own Controllers.

In my eyes I have 3 ways to test my observer:

1. Either performing a feature test by sending a post request to the Nova API
2. Mocking the observer by calling the function in the observer to check if the function perfoms as desired
3. Trying to register my observer on the fly in the AppServiceProvider, performing a request and deregistering the observer in the AppServiceProvider again.

I tried to find a solution for any of these 3 ways to test my observer but unfortunately I faild with any of them.

Problems:

- For way 1 I always get a validation error and Nova tells me that my input is invalid.
- For way 2 I fail at mocking the observer function
- For way 3 I didn't find any solution on how to register and deregister the oberserver on the fly at the AppServiceProvider

Do you guys have idea and solition on how I can test my CommentObserver (which is as written above only registered in my NovaServiceProvider).

---

**Update:**
So, here is the code of my observer. I need to have an valid request to test my observer in order to have the ability to access the `$request->input('images')` variable. I do know I can also use `$comment->content` instead of `request()->input('content')` because `$comment->content` already contains the new content which is not saved it this point.

The reason why I need a valid request is that the variable `images` is not part of the `Comment` model. So I cannot use `$comment->images` because it simply doesn't exist. That's why I need to access the request input. What my observer is basically doing is to extract the `base64` images from the content, saves them to the server and replaces them by an image link.

```
class CommentObserver
{
    public function updating(Comment $comment)
    {
        if (!request()->input('content')) {
            return;
        }

        if (request()->input('content') == $comment->getRawOriginal('content')) {
            return;
        }

        $images = request()->input('images');
        if(!is_array($images)) {
            $images = json_decode(request()->input('images'));
        }

        checkExistingImagesAndDeleteWhenNotFound($comment, request()->input('content'), 'comments', 'medium');
        $comment->content = addBase64ImagesToModelFromContent($comment, request()->input('content'), $images, 'comments', 'medium');
    }
}
```

This is my test so far. I choose way 1 but as described already this always leads to an validation error by the nova controller and I cannot figure out what is the error/what is missing or wrong.

```
class CommentObserverTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_test()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'role_id' => Role::getIdByName('admin')
        ]);

        $product = Product::factory()->create();

        $comment = Comment::factory()->create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'content' => '<p>Das ist wirklich ein super Preis!</p>', 'commentable_type' => 'App\Models\Product', 'commentable_id' => $product->id]);

        $data = [
            'content' => '<p>Das ist wirklich ein HAMMER Preis!</p>',
            'contentDraftId' => '278350e2-1b6b-4009-b4a5-05b92aedaae6',
            'pageStatus' => PageStatus::getIdByStatus('publish'),
            'pageStatus_trashed' => false,
            'commentable' => $product->id,
            'commentable_type' => 'App\Models\Product',
            'commentable_trashed' => false,
            'user' => $user->id,
            'user_trashed' => false,
            '_method' => 'PUT',
            '_retrieved_at' => now()
        ];

        $this->actingAs($user);

        $response = $this->put('http://nova.mywebsiteproject.test/nova-api/comments/' . $comment->id, $data);

        dd($response->decodeResponseJson());

        $das = new CommentObserver();
    }
}
```

Kind regards and thank you

Comment: For each of the three problems you've encountered while writing your first test, which of those tests would you consider the least complex while being most effective for what you would like to know about your code (1, 2 or 3)? For the problem with that one, what would you love to behave instead or you being able to do instead?

Comment: Hi @hakre I think the easiest way would be to write a Laravel Nova feature test and just perform a normal Laravel Nova post request, so number 1. However, this leads always to a validation error. If I would go with way 2 or 3 I would have to fake a request as well because my `updating` method needs to access it.

Comment: @Jan I'd say option 2, except not mocking the observer itself.  Just testing only the observer's functions and nothing else, and mocking any dependencies

Comment: @duncan and how do I fake the HTTP request? Because my observer is accessing the input from the request, so I need to fake it.

Comment: Add your code to your question, both the test and the observer

Comment: Your question is impossible to solve at current information level, please include enough information to let us reproduce your problems.

Comment: I have now added my code. I would be very thankful if you can take a look at it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why depend on the boot method in your `NovaServiceProvider`? It is possible to call the `observe()` method on the fly in your test:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{    
    /** @test */
    public function observe_test()
    {
        Model::observe(ModelObserver::class);


        // If you need the request helper, you can add input like so:
        request()->merge([
           'content' => 'test'
        ]);

        // Fire model event by updating model
        $model->update([
            'someField' => 'someValue',
        ]);

        // Updating should be triggered in ModelObserver
    }
}
```

It should be now be possible in your observer class:

```
public function updating(Model $model)
{
    dd(request()->input('content')); // returns 'test'
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be possible. But then I would need to fake an HTTP Request, because my Observer needs an HTTP Request to work. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: You do not need to fake an HTTP Request, as you're using the helper. You can simply "merge" fields to the request. I have updated my initial comment with a code example.

I have tested this locally and it should work! If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: @Jan Have you tried the above implementation?

Comment: Thank you mate @Eric Landheer . It is working! It took me some time to test it because I was not at home. Sorry for that!